# Почему перестал компилироваться scss?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, scss, less

Здраствуйте, в один момент программа VS Code с помощью плагина Live Sass Compiler перестала проводить компиляцию в обычный CSS. Программу уже переустанавливал и перенастраивал заного по видео-роликам - ничего не помогло. Может быть кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Может быть вы видите какую-то ошибку на панели снизу?

Comment: Да, в панели высвечивается ошибка о том, что компиляция занимает слишком много времени

Comment: А файлы большие scss (или что вы там используете)?